# Unity Mail opens Ubuntu Tour instead of account URL in browser

Tags: unity, mail

The problem is not only with Unity mail but also other applications. For example when I go to *Help* menu in *Sublime 2* and click *Purchase License*, Firefox opens this file:

```
file:///usr/share/doc/ubuntu-online-tour/en/index.html
```

Same with the Unity Mail icon in the menu bar. It used to open the URL I specified in the preferences, but now it takes me to this Online Tour HTML file.

Comment: Found the solution just now. Ubuntu Online Tour was set as default application for web (details / default applications), however that happened. Feel free to remove this question.

Comment: No! Don't remove the question. Please create a new answer with your solution. It can be useful for others users.

Comment: I can't answer my own question as a new user, so I made an edit to the question instead.

Comment: Thanks. I create a community answer with your content. Don't forget to [accept and upvote it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)!

Answer (score 5):

*Resolved by the OP:*

> As it turns out, Ubuntu Online Tour was set as default application for
>   web links. To change this open the dash and search for "Details".
>   Under default applications/Web select your default browser.

[image]